# О передаче параметров в функцию (нужен комментарий)

Tags: c++, c++11

Код:

```
class A {
   public:
       bool foo(T*) const;
} a;

class B {
   public:
       void bar(const T&);
} b;

{
    T *var = new T;
    while( a.foo(var) )
    {
        b.bar(*var);
    }
    delete var;
}

// Прочий код работающий с b
```

Оба класса библиотечные. C функцией `foo()` все хорошо, ее поведение понятно. Но `bar()` вызывает сомнения, не разрушится ли случайно то, что я в нее передал после удаления `var`?

Comment: `b.bar(*var)`  - тогда уж так...

Comment: Да так и есть, опечатка в вопросе, спасибо. Поправил.

Comment: Тогда - "не вижу препятствий" (с)

Comment: Меня смущает то, что объект 'b', живет дольше, чем переменная 'var'. Правильно ли я понимаю, что bar() должна как-то сама беспокоиться о том чтобы сохранить переданное ей значение?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Ведь вы же не говорите, что вы собираетесь делать - сохранять там или еще что. Понятно, что если в `foo` вы сохраняете этот указатель с тем, чтобы использовать его позже - да, у вас будет проблема. Но это ваша проблема - средствами языка избежать ее при по сути нереально. А если вы просто хотите, скажем, вывести какое-то значение из T на экран - проблем не будет. Так что если вы хотите сохранять - сохраняйте копии :)